# I am working in Iterable and am looking to link a different url based on the users state

Tags: dynamic, hyperlink, dynamic-programming

Based on the usera profile and events pulled into Iterable I want to send them a link to a page with information based on their state.
User: John Smith
State: AL

They would recieve in their email an article with a clickable image that hyperlinks to a page about Alabama.

The same would happen with any other user in another state.

I am new to this and am unsure where to start.